# Pyinstaller created executable can not find DLL that is is present in the MEIPASS directory

Tags: python, c++, windows, winapi, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a onefile exe on Windows 7 using PyInstaller.
The executable is created without any errors:

```
88 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
88 INFO: Python: 3.6.9
88 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7600-SP0
88 DEBUG: Testing for UPX ...
90 INFO: UPX is not available.
92 DEBUG: script: numeca\admin_tool\admin_tool.py
93 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\vikramaditya\\Desktop\\admin_tool_2to3',
 'C:\\Users\\vikramaditya\\Desktop\\admin_tool_2to3']
93 INFO: checking Analysis
93 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
93 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
95 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
97 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
97 DEBUG: Collecting submodules for collections
187 DEBUG: collect_submodules - Found submodules: {'collections', 'collections.abc'}
188 DEBUG: Collecting submodules for encodings
293 DEBUG: collect_submodules - Found submodules: {'encodings.cp1006', 'encodings.cp950', 'encodings.undefined', 'encodings.cp852', 'encodings.iso2022_jp_2', 'encodings.cp1026', 'encodings.iso8859_9', 'encodings.johab', 'encodings.iso2022_jp_2004', 'encodings.hz', 'encodings.gb2312', 'encodings.oem', 'encodings.utf_32_be', 'encodings.cp775', 'encodings.kz1048', 'encodings.cp1251', 'encodings.euc_jis_2004', 'encodings.uu_codec', 'encodings.cp857', 'encodings.cp1250', 'encodings.utf_16_le', 'encodings.charmap', 'encodings.iso2022_jp_3', 'encodings.iso8859_11', 'encodings', 'encodings.zlib_codec', 'encodings.aliases', 'encodings.iso8859_5', 'encodings.big5', 'encodings.mac_latin2', 'encodings.iso8859_4', 'encodings.bz2_codec', 'encodings.iso8859_1', 'encodings.utf_16_be', 'encodings.cp65001', 'encodings.mac_iceland', 'encodings.mac_roman', 'encodings.koi8_u', 'encodings.cp864', 'encodings.cp273', 'encodings.unicode_escape', 'encodings.iso2022_jp_1', 'encodings.cp858', 'encodings.iso8859_6', 'encodings.iso2022_jp_ext', 'encodings.cp1254', 'encodings.iso8859_3', 'encodings.palmos', 'encodings.tis_620', 'encodings.iso8859_16', 'encodings.utf_32', 'encodings.iso8859_8', 'encodings.cp875', 'encodings.iso8859_15', 'encodings.rot_13', 'encodings.idna', 'encodings.cp862', 'encodings.euc_jp', 'encodings.mac_croatian', 'encodings.euc_jisx0213', 'encodings.koi8_t', 'encodings.mbcs', 'encodings.koi8_r', 'encodings.cp863'}
3771 DEBUG: Adding python files to base_library.zip
3810 DEBUG: Hidden import: codecs
3810 DEBUG: Hidden import 'codecs' already found
3810 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3810 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\python.exe
3836 DEBUG: Dependent assemblies of c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\python.exe:
3837 DEBUG: *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
3837 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\python.exe
3837 DEBUG: Skipping assembly *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
3845 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python.exe from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
3847 DEBUG: Adding python36.dll dependency of python.exe from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\python36.dll
3849 DEBUG: Skipping KERNEL32.dll dependency of python.exe
3851 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python.exe from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
3853 DEBUG: Adding VCRUNTIME140.dll dependency of python.exe from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\VCRUNTIME140.dll
3854 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python.exe from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
3855 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python.exe from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
3857 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python.exe from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
3857 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
3877 DEBUG: Adding ucrtbase.dll dependency of api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\ucrtbase.dll
3877 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\python36.dll
3878 DEBUG: Dependent assemblies of c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\python36.dll:
3878 DEBUG: *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
3879 DEBUG: Skipping assembly *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
3897 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python36.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
3898 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python36.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
3901 DEBUG: Skipping VERSION.dll dependency of python36.dll
3903 DEBUG: Skipping ADVAPI32.dll dependency of python36.dll
3906 DEBUG: Skipping WS2_32.dll dependency of python36.dll
3908 DEBUG: Skipping SHLWAPI.dll dependency of python36.dll
3910 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python36.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
3911 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python36.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
3913 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python36.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
3915 DEBUG: Skipping KERNEL32.dll dependency of python36.dll
3924 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python36.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
3925 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of python36.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
3925 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
3938 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\VCRUNTIME140.dll
3947 DEBUG: Skipping KERNEL32.dll dependency of VCRUNTIME140.dll
3949 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
3955 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
3965 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
3970 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\ucrtbase.dll
3995 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
3997 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
3998 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
3999 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
4001 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
4002 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
4004 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
4005 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
4006 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll
4008 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
4010 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
4011 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
4013 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll
4014 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
4016 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
4017 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
4018 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
4020 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
4021 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
4023 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
4024 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
4026 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
4027 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
4028 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
4030 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll dependency of ucrtbase.dll from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
4030 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
4036 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
4039 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
4042 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
4054 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
4063 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
4068 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
4071 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
4076 DEBUG: Skipping kernel32.dll dependency of api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
...
4149 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
4156 DEBUG: Skipping kernel32.dll dependency of api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
4158 DEBUG: Skipping normaliz.dll dependency of api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
4158 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
4163 DEBUG: Skipping kernel32.dll dependency of api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
4163 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
4169 DEBUG: Skipping user32.dll dependency of api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
4171 DEBUG: Skipping kernel32.dll dependency of api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
...
4216 INFO: Caching module hooks...
4223 INFO: Analyzing numeca\admin_tool\admin_tool.py
4227 INFO: Loading module hooks...
4227 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
4227 DEBUG: Collecting submodules for encodings
4335 DEBUG: collect_submodules - Found submodules: {'encodings.cp1006', 'encodings.iso2022_jp_1', 'encodings.cp858', 'encodings.iso8859_6', 'encodings.iso2022_jp_ext', 'encodings.cp1254', 'encodings.iso8859_3', 'encodings.palmos', 'encodings.tis_620', 'encodings.iso8859_16', 'encodings.utf_32', 'encodings.iso8859_8', 'encodings.cp875', 'encodings.iso8859_15', 'encodings.rot_13', 'encodings.idna', 'encodings.cp862', 'encodings.euc_jp', 'encodings.mac_croatian', 'encodings.euc_jisx0213', 'encodings.koi8_t', 'encodings.mbcs', 'encodings.koi8_r', 'encodings.cp863'}
4344 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
4345 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
4652 DEBUG: Looking for egg data files...
4652 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
4652 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
4659 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
4660 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
4661 DEBUG: Dependent assemblies of c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\_ssl.pyd:
4662 DEBUG: *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4662 DEBUG: Skipping assembly *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4669 DEBUG: Skipping ADVAPI32.dll dependency of _ssl.pyd
4671 DEBUG: Skipping USER32.dll dependency of _ssl.pyd
4673 DEBUG: Skipping WS2_32.dll dependency of _ssl.pyd
4675 DEBUG: Adding api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of _ssl.pyd from c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
4677 DEBUG: Skipping KERNEL32.dll dependency of _ssl.pyd
4680 DEBUG: Skipping CRYPT32.dll dependency of _ssl.pyd
4682 DEBUG: Skipping GDI32.dll dependency of _ssl.pyd
4682 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
4683 DEBUG: Dependent assemblies of c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd:
4683 DEBUG: *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4684 DEBUG: Skipping assembly *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4689 DEBUG: Skipping KERNEL32.dll dependency of pyexpat.pyd
4689 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
4690 DEBUG: Dependent assemblies of c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd:
4690 DEBUG: *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4690 DEBUG: Skipping assembly *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4696 DEBUG: Skipping KERNEL32.dll dependency of unicodedata.pyd
4696 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
4697 DEBUG: Dependent assemblies of c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd:
4697 DEBUG: *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4698 DEBUG: Skipping assembly *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4704 DEBUG: Skipping ADVAPI32.dll dependency of _hashlib.pyd
4706 DEBUG: Skipping USER32.dll dependency of _hashlib.pyd
4711 DEBUG: Skipping KERNEL32.dll dependency of _hashlib.pyd
4713 DEBUG: Skipping GDI32.dll dependency of _hashlib.pyd
4713 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
4714 DEBUG: Dependent assemblies of c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\_bz2.pyd:
4714 DEBUG: *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4714 DEBUG: Skipping assembly *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4720 DEBUG: Skipping KERNEL32.dll dependency of _bz2.pyd
4720 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
4721 DEBUG: Dependent assemblies of c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\_lzma.pyd:
4721 DEBUG: *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4721 DEBUG: Skipping assembly *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4726 DEBUG: Skipping KERNEL32.dll dependency of _lzma.pyd
4726 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\_socket.pyd
4727 DEBUG: Dependent assemblies of c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\_socket.pyd:
4727 DEBUG: *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4728 DEBUG: Skipping assembly *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4733 DEBUG: Skipping WS2_32.dll dependency of _socket.pyd
4735 DEBUG: Skipping KERNEL32.dll dependency of _socket.pyd
4735 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\select.pyd
4736 DEBUG: Dependent assemblies of c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\DLLs\select.pyd:
4736 DEBUG: *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4736 DEBUG: Skipping assembly *_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.0.0_none
4742 DEBUG: Skipping WS2_32.dll dependency of select.pyd
4744 DEBUG: Skipping KERNEL32.dll dependency of select.pyd
4744 DEBUG: Analyzing c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
4748 INFO: Looking for eggs
4748 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\python36.dll
4748 INFO: Found binding redirects: 
[]
4757 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\build\admin_tool\warn-admin_tool.txt
4812 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\build\admin_tool\xref-admin_tool.html
4835 INFO: Graph drawing written to C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\build\admin_tool\graph-admin_tool.dot
4866 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
4867 INFO: checking PYZ
4867 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
4867 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\build\admin_tool\PYZ-00.pyz
5506 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\build\admin_tool\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
5524 INFO: checking PKG
5524 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
5524 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
5600 DEBUG: Compiling c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
5600 DEBUG: Compiling c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
5602 DEBUG: Compiling C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\numeca\admin_tool\admin_tool.py
5602 DEBUG: Compiling C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\numeca\admin_tool\admin_tool.py
7195 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
7204 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\vikramaditya\desktop\admin_tool_2to3\__build_artifacts__\_tmp_conda_env_3\build_env_windows\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
7204 INFO: checking EXE
7204 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
7204 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
7204 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\dist\admin_tool.exe
7526 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

However, when I try to run the executable it complains that "The program can't start because **api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll** is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem".
After days of searching this is what I know:

1. When the .exe is executed, api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dl is present in the temporary MEIPASS directory. As you will see below, the `SetDllDirectory` has been set to the MEIPASS directory
2. If that api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll is present in the same directory as the .exe, then it does not complain about this DLL. But it complains that it could not find another DLL api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll which is again presnt in the MEIPASS directory. If I copy all the DLLs from MEIPASS to the directory where I have the .exe, then it does not complain and the .exe executes normally.
3. After digging through the bootloader of pyinstaller, I see that the crash happens during the function LoadLibraryExW(dllpath_w, NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) where it is trying to laod the Python36.dll. Changing the `dwFlags` to `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR` is not an option as I do not have [KB2533623](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=217865) installed.
4. I have stripped down my original python script to a `print("Hello World")` and I am able to reproduce the issue even on that script.
5. The executable executes normally on other Windows7 and Windows 10 machines.
6. Including the DLLs from the [CRT](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=windows%207#platform-specific-notes) as mentioned in the pyinstaller documentation did not help.
7. If I set the environment variable PATH to the location of the DLLs then it works.

Here is the execution log:

```
[1128] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[1128] LOADER: executable is C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\dist\admin_tool.exe
[1128] LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\dist
[1128] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[1128] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\dist\admin_tool.exe
[1128] LOADER: Extracting binaries
[1128] LOADER: Executing self as child
[1128] LOADER: set _MEIPASS2 to C:\Users\vikramaditya\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI11282
[1128] LOADER: Setting up to run child
[1128] LOADER: Creating child process
[1128] LOADER: Waiting for child process to finish...
[1172] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[1172] LOADER: executable is C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\dist\admin_tool.exe
[1172] LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\dist
[1172] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is C:\Users\vikramaditya\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI11282
[1172] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\vikramaditya\Desktop\admin_tool_2to3\dist\admin_tool.exe
[1172] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\vikramaditya\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI11282)
[1172] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
[1172] LOADER: manifestpath: C:\Users\vikramaditya\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI11282\admin_tool.exe.manifest
[1172] LOADER: Activation context created
[1172] LOADER: Activation context activated
[1172] LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\vikramaditya\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI11282\python36.dll
```

Has anyone come across something similar? Any ideas on what I should be looking for? I have tried various versions of python3 (the executable used to work correctly when I was on python2) and pyinstaller (3.3.1, 3.4, 3.5).
As you can see from the execution log, the windows 7 version is 7-6.1.7600-SP0 which is not updated but pyinstaller still supports it.

Comment: Have you tried to specified a temp folder with `--runtime-tmpdir PATH`?

Comment: I have tried --runtime-tmpdir but I do not see any change. All it does it to give the location to unzip all the DLLs, so I am not sure why it would even work. Even if it worked, it would not be an option for me as I plan to ship this executable to unknown users whose TMPDIR I do not know about

Comment: Here is the executable, in case you are interested in having a look: https://filebin.net/y7vudcftplokwrvo I suspect that one can reproduce my issue only on Windows 7- SP0

Comment: FYI. I am not able to repro it on windows 10 1903.

Comment: That is the same behavior that I have observed too. The question boils down to: Why can't LoadLibraryExW(python36.dll) not find the dependent DLLs which are in the same directory on only certain Windows machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by building a new bootloader for pyinstaller which would load the CRT DLLs prior to loading Python3x.DLL.

I am sure there must be a more elegant way to do solve the loading issue.